# Struggling to fix infinite loop

Tags: java

I'm new to JUnit testing and I'm struggling to test a method that will search for a specific vehicle registration and output it that it is found

```
   System.out.println("getSpecificVehicle");
    CVMQueue instance = new CVMQueue();
    VehicleNode newVehicle = new VehicleNode("YBZ5484", "Car", "Ire", 3, 2.2);
    instance.enqueue(newVehicle);
    String expResult = "YBZ5484";
    String result = instance.getSpecificVehicle("YBZ5484");
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
```

This is my code, It keeps looping in the Console.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's `temp`? There's no such variable in the code you posted.

Comment: Are you sure that the function getSpecificVehicle("YBZ5484"); should return exactly the same value as the parameter you are providing (should it really return "YBZ5484" and not a VehicleNode?). Some more code about what each function does is helpful otherwise it's mostly guesswork.

Comment: I see `VehicleNode temp = end;` What is `end`?

Comment: it's a Queue position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your code; if you improve the formatting you find

```
while (temp != null) {
...
  if (reg.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getRegNum())) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Your loop is **never** changing temp. So, why should it ever stop looping upon being entered? So, obviously your problem is that you missed that loop-closing brace; as you put that assignment to temp **after** that brace.

But the **real** take-aways here:

1. Formatting matters. Maybe, if you had put more diligence in writing down your code, you would have spotted this yourself much earlier. And as Gaket points out correctly: *any* sane IDE (or coding editor) probably has some "auto format" functionality, that well, formats your source code automatically.
2. Leading to: code readability matters even more. For example, there is the "Single layer of abstraction" principle; which would have told you to **not** just put that complete if into that loop; instead you would have created a **method** to do that work. And again, it would have been so much easier to spot this simple problem.
3. Learn about using a debugger. You see, the real power of unit tests is that they make it **also** so easy to isolate bugs: you put a breakpoint somewhere; and run your test in the debugger; and you can directly observe what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `temp = temp.getNext();` was meant to be inside the while loop but they accidentally put it outside of the loop.

Comment: @Tophandour Correct. But the thing leading there ... bad formatting and such things. That is why my edits completely focus on that part. The bug itself isnt the real thing here; but the circumstances that made that bug happen.

Comment: @HelpImInTrouble And to auto-format your code you can use _Ctrl+Alt+L_ hotkey in Windows. You can look the same command for other OS too.

Comment: @Gaket What IDE are you talking about? For me, ctrl-alt-l locks the screen ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Agreed.

Comment: @GhostCat, default Android studio on Winfows =) You can check your hotkey using top menu, there Code -> Reformat Code. The same works on Intellij Idea. And as I remember, Ctrl+Shift+F will make work in Eclipse

Comment: @Gaket And what makes you think that questioner (or anybody) reading this answer would be using that IDE? What I mean is: when you make such comments, dont expect that kind of content. Rather say something "when using an IDE, there are short cuts to do automated code formatting" or something alike. But still a good point, going to add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point. At least, topicstarter may understand that this way exists and find a concrete implementation in his OS/ide/other editor.

Comment: Okay, I understand this. Should I put the temp = temp.getNext(); within the Loop? Also, Will this solve my unit test?

Comment: @HelpImInTrouble It is your code man; you should understand what it is supposed to do. **You** are the person who should know what should happen in that loop, not us!  ... but seriously: yes, moving that assignment **into** the loop might help; but of course: what happens then depends on what temp.getNext() will be doing. Same for the other answer - what happens in your unit test then ... only **you** can find out.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes I am aware of this, Thanks for your help. The Loop was causing the issue and it passed the test. I'll create a separate method for that IF statement. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that ... then dont forget about accepting the answer ;-)